# get parameters from referrer

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there any easy way to extract the parameters of the referrer url as contained in Request.UrlReferrer? Is there another way to get the parameters used by the referrer?

> Query?blahID=3&name=blah

I am refering to getting blahID and name from the url. It can be done with a bunch of string manipulations, but was hoping there was an easier way.

Comment: @Allov Well I do not know everything, ParseQueryString do the job.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` from `System.Web`. Something like this should work:

```
string blahID = string.Empty;
if(Request.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.UrlReferrer.Query);
    blahID = q["blahID"];
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it returns only the keys from the string, not the values. It is also not removing the unnecessary `&amp;` string from the beginning of the keys/parameter name. I also have a parameter in the ReferrerUrl that contains a URL string. The URL string value needs to be parses correctly too as that also contains special characters that are not needed. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: @naz786 I would ask another question and try to provide a code example. Feel free to reference this question if you think it would help.